# css trick disable text selection on copy-paste

Tags: html, css

I have a sequence of letters with numbers on top of each letter. I want to disable text selection, so that when the user copy paste the sequence of letters from the screen, he does not get numbers.

I'm actually using no select css trick and the numbers are excluded from selection, but I get a space where the number was. Like so:

```
T

QD
```

The desired output is instead:

```
TQD
```

Here is my code:

```html
<div style="margin-bottom:0px;font-size: 0.65vw;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:1.3vw;font-size: 0.8vw; text-align: center">
  <p style="-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;background-color:#ededed;margin: 0px;font-size:0.6vw;padding-top: 2px; height:0.6vw;">1</p>
  <span style="background-color:hsl(60,100%,60%);width:1.3vw;font-size: 0.8vw;display:inline-block;text-align: center;padding-top:2px">T</span></div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:1.3vw;font-size: 0.8vw; text-align: center">
<p style="-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;background-color:#ededed;margin: 0px;font-size:0.6vw;padding-top: 2px; height:0.6vw;">2</p>
<span style="background-color:hsl(60,100%,60%);width:1.3vw;font-size: 0.8vw;display:inline-block;text-align: center;padding-top:2px">Q</span></div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:1.3vw;font-size: 0.8vw; text-align: center">
<p style="-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-touch-callout: none;background-color:#ededed;margin: 0px;font-size: 0.6px;padding-top: 2px;height:0.6vw;"></p>
<span style="background-color:hsl(60,100%,60%);width:1.3vw;font-size: 0.8vw;display:inline-block;text-align: center;padding-top:2px">D</span></div></div>
```

Is there any css trick for this?

Comment: You can use [document.execCommand("copy");](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard) and provide a button that will copy exactly what you want to the clipboard, I don't understand this feature though - It sound unnecessary

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me, it still copies numbers (Using Mac os)

Comment: @Wimanicesir what browser are you using?

Comment: Hi @mb925 , You can use javascript for disabling right click and ctrl button then copy paste will automatically disable.

Comment: My bad @Wimanicesir, please check I have EDITED the code snippet and it should work now.

Comment: Yes, it works now!

Answer (score 0):

If you can disable the ctrl button and right click from a webpage then the functionality copy paste will automatically disable. I think the following code will help you.

```
<script>
  $(window).on('keydown',function(event)
 {
 if(event.keyCode==123)
 {
    alert(' Developer Tools is disable from this website.');
    return false;
 }
 else if(event.keyCode==17)
 {
    alert('Control key is disable from this website.');
    return false;
 }    

  });
  $(document).on("contextmenu",function(e)
 {
   alert('Right click is disable from this website!')
  e.preventDefault();
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: I actually want to keep the copy paste functionality, because I need to copy the letters. 
The only thing I don't need are numbers on top of letters. They get disabled in my code, but a white space is left on their spot. I don't need that space either, it should copy only letters.

Comment: Disabling Developer tools by key isn't foolproof btw

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution! I'm using the tag **p** which is a block element, this is why it will leave a space where the tag was. On the contrary, using some inline element such as **b** or **span** will not leave any space.